# Custom stream manipulator for streaming integers in any base

Tags: c++, iostream

I can make an `std::ostream` object output integer numbers in hex, for example

```
std::cout << std::hex << 0xabc; //prints `abc`, not the base-10 representation
```

Is there any manipulator that is universal for all bases? Something like

```
std::cout << std::base(4) << 20; //I want this to output 110
```

If there is one, then I have no further question.
If there isn't one, then can I write one? Won't it require me to access private implementation details of `std::ostream`?

Note that I know I can write a function that takes a number and converts it to a string which is the representation of that number in any base. Or I can use one that already exists. I am asking about custom stream manipulators - are they possible?

Comment: @Armen: I wrote a code, but that doesn't print `50` when you write `std::cout << std::base(4) << 20`. Can you explain why do you want `50` as output? My program prints `110` instead. I'm a bit confused, so I didn't post my code as answer.

Comment: @Nawaz: Naturally, `"50"` isn't a valid base 4 number, since the only allowed digits are 0-3.

Comment: @Ben: Yeah. That is what is the source of confusion. I think @Armen calculated it wrong, in hurry!

Comment: @Armen: It would be better if you change the topic to `Custom stream manipulator for streaming integers in any base`, or something more descriptive.. But the idea is, the title should contain `Custom stream manipulator` phrase.

Comment: Related question: [C++ custom stream manipulator that changes next item on stream - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799599/c-custom-stream-manipulator-that-changes-next-item-on-stream)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do something like the following.  I have commented the code to explain what each part is doing, but essentially its this:

- Create a "manipulator" struct which stores some data in the stream using [`xalloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/xalloc/) and  [`iword`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/iword/).
- Create a custom [`num_put`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/num_put/) facet which looks for your manipulator and applies the manipulation.

Here is the code...

**Edit:** Note that im not sure I handled the `std::ios_base::internal` flag correctly here - as I dont actually know what its for.

**Edit 2:** I found out what `std::ios_base::internal` is for, and updated the code to handle it.

**Edit 3:** Added a call to `std::locacle::global` to show how to make all the standard stream classes support the new stream manipulator by default, rather than having to `imbue` them.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <climits>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

namespace StreamManip {

// Define a base manipulator type, its what the built in stream manipulators
// do when they take parameters, only they return an opaque type.
struct BaseManip
{
    int mBase;

    BaseManip(int base) : mBase(base)
    {
        assert(base >= 2);
        assert(base <= 36);
    }

    static int getIWord()
    {
        // call xalloc once to get an index at which we can store data for this
        // manipulator.
        static int iw = std::ios_base::xalloc();
        return iw;
    }

    void apply(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        // store the base value in the manipulator.
        os.iword(getIWord()) = mBase;
    }
};

// We need this so we can apply our custom stream manipulator to the stream.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BaseManip& bm)
{
    bm.apply(os);
    return os;
}

// convience function, so we can do std::cout << base(16) << 100;
BaseManip base(int b)
{
    return BaseManip(b);
}

// A custom number output facet.  These are used by the std::locale code in
// streams.  The num_put facet handles the output of numberic values as characters
// in the stream.  Here we create one that knows about our custom manipulator.
struct BaseNumPut : std::num_put<char>
{
    // These absVal functions are needed as std::abs doesnt support 
    // unsigned types, but the templated doPutHelper works on signed and
    // unsigned types.
    unsigned long int absVal(unsigned long int a) const
    {
        return a;
    }

    unsigned long long int absVal(unsigned long long int a) const
    {
        return a;
    }

    template <class NumType>
    NumType absVal(NumType a) const
    {
        return std::abs(a);
    }

    template <class NumType>
    iter_type doPutHelper(iter_type out, std::ios_base& str, char_type fill, NumType val) const
    {
        // Read the value stored in our xalloc location.
        const int base = str.iword(BaseManip::getIWord());

        // we only want this manipulator to affect the next numeric value, so
        // reset its value.
        str.iword(BaseManip::getIWord()) = 0;

        // normal number output, use the built in putter.
        if (base == 0 || base == 10)
        {
            return std::num_put<char>::do_put(out, str, fill, val);
        }

        // We want to conver the base, so do it and output.
        // Base conversion code lifted from Nawaz's answer

        int digits[CHAR_BIT * sizeof(NumType)];
        int i = 0;
        NumType tempVal = absVal(val);

        while (tempVal != 0)
        {
            digits[i++] = tempVal % base;
            tempVal /= base;
        }

        // Get the format flags.
        const std::ios_base::fmtflags flags = str.flags();

        // Add the padding if needs by (i.e. they have used std::setw).
        // Only applies if we are right aligned, or none specified.
        if (flags & std::ios_base::right || 
            !(flags & std::ios_base::internal || flags & std::ios_base::left))
        {
            std::fill_n(out, str.width() - i, fill);
        }

        if (val < 0)
        {
            *out++ = '-';
        }

        // Handle the internal adjustment flag.
        if (flags & std::ios_base::internal)
        {
            std::fill_n(out, str.width() - i, fill);
        }

        char digitCharLc[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        char digitCharUc[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        const char *digitChar = (str.flags() & std::ios_base::uppercase)
            ? digitCharUc
            : digitCharLc;

        while (i)
        {
            // out is an iterator that accepts characters
            *out++ = digitChar[digits[--i]];
        }

        // Add the padding if needs by (i.e. they have used std::setw).
        // Only applies if we are left aligned.
        if (str.flags() & std::ios_base::left)
        {
            std::fill_n(out, str.width() - i, fill);
        }

        // clear the width
        str.width(0);

        return out;
    }

    // Overrides for the virtual do_put member functions.

    iter_type do_put(iter_type out, std::ios_base& str, char_type fill, long val) const
    {
        return doPutHelper(out, str, fill, val);
    }

    iter_type do_put(iter_type out, std::ios_base& str, char_type fill, unsigned long val) const
    {
        return doPutHelper(out, str, fill, val);
    }
};

} // namespace StreamManip

int main()
{
    // Create a local the uses our custom num_put
    std::locale myLocale(std::locale(), new StreamManip::BaseNumPut());

    // Set our locacle to the global one used by default in all streams created 
    // from here on in.  Any streams created in this app will now support the
    // StreamManip::base modifier.
    std::locale::global(myLocale);

    // imbue std::cout, so it uses are custom local.
    std::cout.imbue(myLocale);
    std::cerr.imbue(myLocale);

    // Output some stuff.
    std::cout << std::setw(50) << StreamManip::base(2) << std::internal << -255 << std::endl;
    std::cout << StreamManip::base(4) << 255 << std::endl;
    std::cout << StreamManip::base(8) << 255 << std::endl;
    std::cout << StreamManip::base(10) << 255 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::uppercase << StreamManip::base(16) << 255 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Ben - Thanks, when done once as part of a library, its not too much work.  But yes, the same result could be achieved with simpler code, I mainly wanted to show that you can make custom stream manipulators.

Comment: Warning: This code has some bugs: 1. Doesn't output "0". 2. Doesn't count minus sign for padding. 3. Padding for left alignment uses "i" which is already counted down to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Custom manipulators are indeed possible. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535444/custom-manipulator-for-c-iostream). I'm not familiar with any specific one for universal bases.

Answer (score 2):

You really have two separate problems. The one I think you're asking about is entirely solvable. The other, unfortunately, is rather less so.

Allocating and using some space in the stream to hold some stream state is a problem that was foreseen. Streams have a couple of members (`xalloc`, `iword`, `pword`) that let you allocate a spot in an array in the stream, and read/write data there. As such, the stream manipulator itself is entirely possible. You'd basically use `xalloc` to allocate a spot in the stream's array to hold the current base, to be used by the insertion operator when it converts a number.

The problem for which I don't see a solution is rather simpler: the standard library already provides an `operator<<` to insert an `int` into a stream, and it obviously does *not* know about your hypothetical data to hold the base for a conversion. You can't overload that, because it would need exactly the same signature as the existing one, so your overload would be ambiguous.

The overloads for `int`, `short`, etc., however, are overloaded member functions. I *guess* if you wanted to badly enough, you could get by with using a template to overload `operator<<`. If I recall correctly, that would be preferred over even an exact match with a non-template function as the library provides.  You'd still be breaking the rules, but if you put such a template in namespace std, there's at least some chance that it would work.

Answer (score 2):

I attempted to write a code, and its working with some limitations. Its not stream manipulator as such, as that is simply not possible, as pointed out by others (especially @Jerry).

Here is my code:

```
struct base
{
   mutable std::ostream *_out;
   int _value;

   base(int value=10) : _value(value) {}

   template<typename T>
   const base& operator << (const T & data) const
   {
        *_out << data;
        return *this;
   }
   const base& operator << (const int & data) const
   {
        switch(_value)
        {
            case 2:  
            case 4:  
            case 8:  return print(data);
            case 16: *_out << std::hex << data; break;
            default:  *_out << data; 
        }
        return *this;
   }
   const base & print(int data) const
   {
        int digits[CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)], i = 0;
        while(data)
        {
             digits[i++] = data % _value;  
             data /= _value;
        }
        while(i) *_out << digits[--i] ;
        return *this;
   }
   friend const base& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const base& b)   
   {
       b._out = &out;
       return b;
   }
};
```

And this is the test code:

```
int main() {
   std::cout << base(2) << 255 <<", " << 54 << ", " << 20<< "\n";
   std::cout << base(4) << 255 <<", " << 54 << ", " << 20<< "\n";
   std::cout << base(8) << 255 <<", " << 54 << ", " << 20<< "\n";
   std::cout << base(16) << 255 <<", " << 54 << ", " << 20<< "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
11111111, 110110, 10100
3333, 312, 110
377, 66, 24
ff, 36, 14
```

Online demo : http://www.ideone.com/BWhW5

Limitations:

- The base cannot be changed twice. So this would be an error:

  ```
  std::cout << base(4) << 879 << base(8) << 9878 ; //error
  ```
- Other manipulator cannot be used after `base` is used:

  ```
  std::cout << base(4) << 879 << std::hex << 9878 ; //error
  std::cout << std::hex << 879 << base(8) << 9878 ; //ok
  ```
- `std::endl` cannot be used after `base` is used:

  ```
  std::cout << base(4) << 879 << std::endl ; //error
  //that is why I used "\n" in the test code.
  ```

Comment: @gigantt's link provides the same ability with far fewer limitations.

Comment: +1 This is roughly what I would have done. You can easily add the ability to change bases by overloading `operator<<(const base&)`, and probably fix the manipulator issue by overloading `operator<<(ostream&(*)(ostream&))`, `operator<<(ios&(*)(ios&))`, and `operator<<(ios_base&(*)(ios_base&))`.

Comment: @Jon: Nice idea. I will do it sometime. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that syntax is possible for arbitrary streams (using a manipulator, @gigantt linked an answer that shows some alternative non-manipulator solutions).  The standard manipulators merely set options that are implemented inside the stream.

OTOH, you could certainly make this syntax work:

```
std::cout << base(4, 20);
```

Where `base` is an object that provides a stream insertion operator (no need to return a temporary `string`).

Comment: +1: This surely is the most robust, simple and versatile solution.

Comment: You can make custom stream manipulators using `xalloc`, `iword` and custom facets.