# How to format flags in c++?

Tags: c++

I know in c++ we can format the output/input using state flags like ios::showbase... I know that we can set the flag for basefield to hex,oct,dec but is there bin? and how to format integers in binary basefield?

Comment: Yeah sorry misunderstood

Comment: no worries! I welcome any comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `bitset<>`. For example:

```
    int x = 1025;
    std::cout << std::bitset<32>(x) << std::endl;
```

The above will produce the output:

```
00000000000000000000010000000001
```

Comment: At last could you explain a bit why there is not ios::bin?

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't mandate it.  I don't think it would be prudent for me to speculate as to why.

Comment: @Jxh which library file include definition of `bitset`, `iomanip` giving error. and why `setbase(2)` not works ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane: (1) `#include <bitset>` (2) `setbase()` is only defined to react to 8, 16, or 10.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that many people are happy with the approach using a `std::bitset<N>` to print the relevant value. Although this sort of work, I like to point out that it *is* possible to write a `bin` manipulator although it is a bit involved: you'd derive from `std::num_put<char>` and install a `std::locale` using the corresponding facet. Below is an implementation of this approach. Look at the function `print()` at the bottom to see the "nice" code - the top is just making things happen with the `std::nun_put<char>` facet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <limits>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int bin_index(std::ios_base::xalloc());

struct num_put
    : std::num_put<char>
{
public:
    num_put(std::locale const& chain)
        : d_chain(std::use_facet<std::num_put<char> >(chain)) {
    }
private:
#if __cplusplus == 201103L
    typedef long long          long_forward;
    typedef unsigned long long actual_type;
#else
    typedef unsigned long long_forward;
    typedef unsigned long actual_type;
#endif

    std::num_put<char> const& d_chain;
    typedef std::num_put<char>::iter_type iter_type;
    iter_type do_put(iter_type to, std::ios_base& fmt, char_type fill,
                     long v) const {
        return fmt.iword(bin_index)
            ? this->put(to, fmt, fill, static_cast<long_forward>(v))
            : this->d_chain.put(to, fmt, fill, v);
    }
#if __cplusplus == 201103L
    iter_type do_put(iter_type to, std::ios_base& fmt, char_type fill,
                     long long v) const {
        return fmt.iword(bin_index)
            ? this->put(to, fmt, fill, static_cast<unsigned long long>(v))
            : this->d_chain.put(to, fmt, fill, v);
    }
    iter_type do_put(iter_type to, std::ios_base& fmt, char_type fill,
                     unsigned long v) const {
        return fmt.iword(bin_index)
            ? this->put(to, fmt, fill, static_cast<unsigned long long>(v))
            : this->d_chain.put(to, fmt, fill, v);
    }
#endif
    iter_type do_put(iter_type to, std::ios_base& fmt, char_type fill,
                     actual_type v) const {
        if (fmt.iword(bin_index)) {
            char  bits[std::numeric_limits<actual_type>::digits];
            char* end(bits);
            if (v == 0) {
                *end++ = '0';
            }
            else {
                for (; v; ++end) {
                    *end = "01"[v & 0x1u];
                    v >>= 1;
                }
            }
            std::streamsize show(2 * (bool(fmt.flags()
                                           & std::ios_base::showbase)));
            std::streamsize nofill(show + end - bits < fmt.width()
                                   ? fmt.width() - (show + end - bits)
                                   : 0);
            fmt.width(0);
            if (0 < nofill && (fmt.flags() & std::ios_base::right)) {
                end = std::fill_n(end, nofill, fill);
            }
            if (fmt.flags() & std::ios_base::showbase) {
                *end++ = 'b';
                *end++ = '0';
            }
            if (0 < nofill && (fmt.flags() & std::ios_base::internal)) {
                end = std::fill_n(end, nofill, fill);
            }
            to = std::copy(std::reverse_iterator<char*>(end),
                             std::reverse_iterator<char*>(bits),
                             to);
            if (0 < nofill && (fmt.flags() & std::ios_base::left)) {
                to = std::fill_n(to, nofill, fill);
            }
            return to;
        }
        else {
            return this->d_chain.put(to, fmt, fill, v);
        }
    }
};

std::ostream& bin(std::ostream& out)
{
    if (!dynamic_cast<num_put const*>(
            &std::use_facet<std::num_put<char> >(out.getloc()))) {
        std::locale loc(std::locale(), new num_put(out.getloc()));
        out.imbue(loc);
    }
    out.iword(bin_index) = true;
    return out;
}

std::ostream& nobin(std::ostream& out)
{
    out.iword(bin_index) = false;
    return out;
}

void print(int value)
{
    std::cout << std::right;
    std::cout << nobin << std::setw(8) << value << "="
              << bin << std::right << std::setw(20) << value << "'\n";
    std::cout << nobin << std::setw(8) << value << "="
              << bin << std::internal << std::setw(20) << value << "'\n";
    std::cout << nobin << std::setw(8) << value << "="
              << bin << std::left << std::setw(20) << value << "'\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::showbase;
    print(0);
    print(17);
    print(123456);
}
```

Comment: when i compile this code I got 20 compile-time erros; on of them: error C2632: 'long' followed by 'long' is illegal

Comment: @ProDev7: It seems you are not using C++11! In that case things need to be structured slightly different. I'll update the answer as soon as I have a version doing both...

Comment: @ProDev7: I have updated the code to compile with both C++03 and C++11 and use the appropriate overwritten versions of `do_put()` (I think; it isn't too thoroughly tested).

Answer (score 0):

You can also add your own stream manipulator like described here:

[Custom stream manipulator for streaming integers in any base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478745/custom-stream-manipulator-for-streaming-integers-in-any-base/6479634#6479634)