# How to execute std::left from a string

Tags: c++

I am trying to have a function `myCout`  that have a string among its argument. This string is meant to set the alignment of the output. That is is if we have `"left"` as argument 
`cout<<std::left;` should be executed .

I have attached my code below.

```
ostream & myAlign (string str) {

        if (str == "left")
            return  std ::left ; 
        else 
            return std::right ;
}

template <class T>
void myCout (int width, char fill, T var, string a) {

    cout << setw(width) << setfill(fill) << setprecision(2) << myAlign(a) << std:: fixed << var << "\t" <<flush ;    
    return ;
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: You might want to check e.g. [this reference of I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), especially the ones about the [manipulators you use](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left).

Comment: @TobiasWärre Wut? I'm pretty sure you can, since you have defined [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp), see case (7).

Comment: @TobiasWärre Not sure where you're getting your information, or how you got an upvote. Comparing a `std::string` with a string literal is perfectly OK.

Comment: @TobiasWärre: that is *not* correct.

Comment: @luk32, Well look at that, I must have missed it...

Answer (score 4):

IO manipulators are not magic, but they can be odd to think about. There are several ways to do this, this being just one of them, mimicking the behavior it appears you're looking for..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class myAlign
{
public:
    explicit myAlign(const std::string& s)
        : fmt((s == "left") ? std::ios::left : std::ios::right)
    {}

private:
    std::ios::fmtflags fmt;

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const myAlign& arg)
    {
        os.setf(arg.fmt);
        return os;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << myAlign("left") << std::setw(10) << "12345" << std::endl;
    std::cout << myAlign("right") << std::setw(10) << "67890" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
12345     
     67890
```

Note: A similar but considerably more complex related question [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478745/custom-stream-manipulator-for-streaming-integers-in-any-base).

Comment: Thank you so much for your anwers ,Trully helpfull