# double to std::cout truncates data

Tags: c++, string, double, cout

```
int main(){
    std::string text = "15555555.2587";
    std::stringstream ss;
    double number;
    ss << text;
    ss >> number;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setw( 11 ) << std::setprecision( 6 ) 
      << std::setfill( '0' ) << number<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output of the above program is 15555555.0000

it truncates the value after the decimal point.

how do I get the correct value?

Comment: I think it depends on some local settings. Try with replacing the `.` with `,`. It's a guess, but..

Comment: By default double values are displayed to 6 figures. Look up setprecision.

Comment: if I set the value of sting to 15555555.2587, the program returns 15555555.0000

Comment: As Kiril Kirov said, it might be a locale issue if precision does not help. Possibly the locale set on your system uses some other symbol instead of '.' (',' would be a good guess for several European languages e.g. German). Which locale are you using?

Comment: My system is using '.' for decimal notation

Comment: for 155555.2587 its output is correct, but for 15555555.2587 its output is 15555555.0000

Comment: @RiteshBanka Well then, it _is_ a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989374/floating-point-format-for-stdostream

Comment: I used the same command to print the result but I am getting wrong output so thought of posting it as a new question

Comment: It would be easier if you didn't keep changing the question. What happens if you increase precision now? Have you considered reading the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correct value in `number` as expected. The problem is you should print it by `cout` in this way:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << number;
```

Output

```
155555.2587
```

Comment: if I set the value of sting to 15555555.2587, the program returns 15555555.0000

Comment: It prints `15555555.2587` -- See [this live test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ec4d6ec7e4bed00).

Comment: I used 
g++ -O3 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp 
to compile my program and it outputs 15555555.0000

Comment: My program returns correct output for 155555.2587 but not for 15555555.2587

Comment: @RiteshBanka: I tried various switch for gcc and all of them print right value

Answer (score 1):

As Alan Stokes said, streams are configured to print floating-point values with 6 decimal digits by default. You could modify this behaviour through stream manipulators like [`std::setprecision()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision):

```
int main()
{
    float pi = 3.141592654;

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 4 ) << pi << std::endl;
}
```

The code above prints:

> 3,1416

Comment: @Caesar thats not a big number at all. As Philip said, try to change the output layout

Comment: Sorry, +1 to make up for it

Comment: Am I the only one worried about the fact that it prints "3.1415" instead of "3.1416" ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. uups, my fault. Thanks