# Formatting output when rewriting program from C to C++

Tags: c++

In the original C program the output was done as

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    printf("%-10.4lf", x[i]);
```

and it looks like

```
23.4500   22.4420   65.2300   82.3000   7.0000    104.0900
```

The C++ edition

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    std::cout << x[i];
```

make output as

```
23.4522.44265.2382.37104.09
```

What should be changed in C++ edition to see the same result?

Comment: You can still use `std::printf("%-10.4lf", x[i]);`, this would be less work than translating.

Comment: The task is to use cout

Comment: You can mix `printf()` and `cout` freely.  The `std::cout` code is going to be fairly verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `setw` and `setprecision`.

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
     std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << x[i];
     std::cout << std::setw(10);  
}
```

Comment: setprecision( 4 )  was found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989374/floating-point-format-for-stdostream

Comment: but still no answer for alignment

Comment: @petrovich: It seems like you're asking us to look stuff up for you: you might find it easier to just do that part yourself.  See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip (In particular, once you know about `setw`, your next step could be to Google it, and you'd learn that it's called an io manipulator, and you'd find a list of other io manipulators)

Comment: @Dietrich Epp : thank you, it is useful

Comment: Agreed with @DietrichEpp. Look at `std::left`.