# How can I change the displayed value of a double when outputting to the console in Eclipse Kepler, C++, (mac OS X)?

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, long-double

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

class Project3
{
public:
    long double divbythree()
    {
        while (i<halfprime){
            primefactor = prime/i;
            ++i;
            if (primefactor == (long long int)primefactor){
            //if (modf(primeoverthree, 0) == 0){
                cout << "Prime factor is: " << primefactor << endl;
                cout << "Denominator is: " << i << endl;
            }
            else{/*empty else statement*/   }
        }
        cout << primefactor << endl;
        return prime;
    }
private:
    long double primefactor = 1;
    long double prime = 600851475143;
    long double halfprime = 300425737570;
    long double i = 1;
};


int main() {
    Project3 Pro3;
    Pro3.divbythree();

    return 0;
}
```

...and here is my output:

```
Prime factor is: 6.00851e+11
Denominator is: 2
Prime factor is: 8.4627e+09
Denominator is: 72
Prime factor is: 7.16152e+08
Denominator is: 840
```

Etc.

Is there any way to change the IDE settings so that the console shows all elements of the double?

Or maybe so that output displays to some decimal place, i.e. to 5 decimal places.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Edit: Answer here: [How to 'cout' the correct number of decimal places of a double value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217510/how-to-cout-the-correct-number-of-decimal-places-of-a-double-value)

Comment: Do you _really_ need this 'empty else statement'??

Comment: [Possible duplicate #2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989374/floating-point-format-for-stdostream)

Comment: Does it bother you @ForceBru hahaha