# explicit type casting float(intvar) results in int

Tags: c++, floating-point, cout

I tried the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int intvar = 25;
    float floatvar = 35.87;
    cout << "intvar= " << intvar;
    cout << "\n floatvar =" << floatvar;
    cout << "\n float(intvar)=" << float(intvar);
    cout << "\n int(floatvar)=" << int(floatvar);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The result for `float(intvar)` is coming as `25`.
Can someone please explain why it is still being shown as an integer and not `25.000000`?

Comment: Because they mean the same? And how exactly you chose the number of zeroes? Anyway, this may be helpful, if you want to format the output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989374/floating-point-format-for-stdostream/11989420#11989420

Answer (score 3):

The value is not an integer, it's just that `std::cout` will try to give you a compact representation here. Use `setfixed` and `setprecision` (from `#include <iomanip>`) to force a specific output precision on floats. Add this before the first `cout` line:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(6);
```

Comment: I had the doubt because i expected float to print a decimal no. And not just an integer. But thank u, will try ur suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the format for floatingPoint output, such as:

```
cout << "\n float(intvar)=" << std::fixed << float(intvar);
```

From [The.C++.Programming.Language.Special.Edition] 21.4.3 FloatingPoint Output [io.out.float]:

> Floatingpoint output is controlled by a format and a precision:
>
> – The
> general format lets the implementation choose a format that presents a
> value in the style that best preserves the value in the space
> available. The precision specifies the maximum number of digits. It
> corresponds to printf()’s %g (§21.8).
>
> – The scientific format presents
> a value with one digit before a decimal point and an exponent. The
> precision specifies the maximum number of digits after the decimal
> point. It corresponds to printf()’s %e .
>
> – The fixed format presents a
> value as an integer part followed by a decimal point and a fractional
> part. The precision specifies the maximum number of digits after the
> decimal point. It corresponds to printf()’s %f .